# Change of boarding point on Indian Railways

Tags: trains, tickets, bookings, train-stations

i have booked my online  ticket through irctc.co.in from Mumbai to chennai, but i forgot to change the boarding point to pune. will my seat will be empty when i board at pune. or else any procedure is there to change the boarding point, 
if there is a procedure to change to which station i have to approach

Comment: Can you clarify whether the train stops at Pune before or after it stops at Mumbai?  Not everybody is familiar with Indian geography.

Answer (score 3):

Since you have booked your ticket through IRCTC's website, when you go to the 'Booked Ticket History' page, there is an option to 'Change boarding point' in addition to 'Cancel ticket', 'Get PNR Status' etc. You can use the change boarding point option to make changes to your desired boarding point, which in your case is Pune.