# How to change my Indian Railway boarding point online?

Tags: trains, india

I booked my ticket from Kolkata (KOAA) to Malda Town (MLDT). But by mistake I gave boarding point at Barddhaman (BWN) which is the very next station after Kolkata and there is no other stoppage in between these two stations. How to solve this problem?

Comment: This question might be a bit hard to read (English might not be the OP's first language) but it's clear enough to me; I just don't know the answer.

Comment: You might find my [answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/63999/change-of-boarding-point-on-indian-railways/64000#64000) to a previous post helpful

Answer (score 3):

so you want to go from kolkata to malda town? But you booked from barddhaman? From my experience of booking indian trains you cannot change the station, you just have to buy a new ticket. However if you are doing it with enough time in advance you can get a refund on your original ticket.

So either you get a refund for the whole ticket and buy a new one or you buy a new ticket to get from kolkata to bardhhaman only, then you will have your full journey. The second option may be easier.

Answer (score 1):

You have 3 options as follows:

1. Book reserve ticket from Kolkata to Barddhaman for the same train (if not available then book other train which will reach Barddhaman before the train you booked currently) and for the journey from Barddhaman to Malda Town use your existing ticket.
2. Book unreserved ticket from Kolkata to Barddhaman on the day of journey and go the Barddhaman, then for the journey from Barddhaman to Malda Town use your existing ticket.
3. Cancel your existing ticket and book a new one.

**Note:** For option 1 & 3 please check whether there are sufficiant tickets available